# Build Tensorflow r1.0 c++ API

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I trying to build Tensorflow r1.0 for c++
I was able to compile the libtensorflow.so but not all the headers generated.
All the ops headers missing except from standard_ops.h and const_ops.h which include in them all the ops headers that missing.

Im using Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

Code for most ops is generated during the build. When using `bazel`, you should fine the generated header files in: `bazel-genfiles/tensorflow/cc/ops`, e.g., `bazel-genfiles/tensorflow/cc/ops/math_ops.h`.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using CMake, you can use [tensorflow_cc](https://github.com/FloopCZ/tensorflow_cc) project. It builds and installs TF C++ API for you, along with convenient CMake targets you can link against.